# Elisp -> Merge all the files in a directory into one file

Tags: elisp

I'd like to make a function to merge all the emacs configuration files within a folder into one file.
Now I do this using a bash script file, which looks like this:

```
> init.el
for d in ./defun/*.el ; do
    cat $d >> init.el
    echo $d
done
```

I know Emacs has a 'merge' option, but it only merges 2 files.

Thank you very much in advance for helping!

Comment: what's wrong with `cat defun/*.el > init.el` at the shell prompt or `(shell-command "cat defun/*.el > init.el")` in emacs lisp?

Comment: Brilliant! Rephrasing it from 'What's wrong with' to 'Have you tried' and that was actually the solution to my problem: (shell-command)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your script to a single command:

```
cat defun/*.el > init.el
```

which you can pass directly to [`shell-command`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Single-Shell.html).